# Printer Driver in macOS Sierra

Tags: printing, macos

I'm currently trying to install a [Dell 1130n Printer Driver](http://www.dell.com/support/home/au/en/aubsdt1/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=R264076) on macOS Sierra.

Upon installation, the installer displays this message:

> Error opening file: libscmssc.dylib
>   1008:6, -35 Drive not found

This file is located in a folder in the same directory as the installation file.

I have disabled some security settings in macOS Sierra by running a line of code in Terminal, which I thought might have caused that issue:

```
sudo spctl --master-disable
```

But it does not appear to have any effect on the installer.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, that installer is from 2011 so it may not work anymore... The following site suggests they dropped support for it in 10.10:

http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN294375/EN

That being said, does it work if you select a generic driver?

Looks like people have used the SAMSUNG ML-191x 252x SERIES driver with success previously:  http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/peripherals/f/3528/t/19450382

Comment: This appears to work for now! Thank you so much, I'll report back if I have any other difficulties.

The installer from 2011 did work on OSX El Capitan so I'm unsure on why it doesn't work on macOS Sierra.

Comment: For Sierra (and later), the drivers aren't included, but are available at this site: https://support.apple.com/kb/dl905?locale=en_US